# Concatenating unicode strings based on length

Tags: python, unicode, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a unicode text which is broken into different segments. I want to concatenate them based on their lengths, but make sure no segment is repeated.
Here is psuedo-cdoe:

```
i=0
text = 'whole text'
spaceString = ' '
avgLength = len(text)/len(total number of segments)
newtext=[]
previousLength = len(segments[i-1])
nextLength = len(segments[i+1])
for each segment [i]:
    if len(segments[i])<avgLength:
        compare previousLength and nextLength and get the lower result
        Concatenate segment[i] to either segment[i+1] or segment[i-1] (and attach to newtext) depending on which is lower
    else if segment[i]>=avgLength:
         Attach segment[i] to newtext and move to next segment


    elif . . .
```

The aim is to join segments which are less than the average length. If any segment is smaller than the average length, compare `previousLength` and `nextLength`, and join `segment i` to the one which is less. (The first segment might be less or greater than the average). However, if any segment is more than the average length, just append that segment. `newtext` should be similar to `text` but should contain segments which are more or equal to the length of the average segment.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understood from your question, I have wrriten the following code.

If it is not what you are looking for, could you please clarify your requirements and I can edit the code appropriately. - Maybe try to write it in psuedo code?

Code:

```
temp_string = ''
for i in range(len(segments)):
  if len(segments[i]) < avgLength:
    #if it is in the temp string do nothing to avoid repitition
    #else add to temp_string
    if segments[i] in temp_string:
      continue
    else:
      temp_string += spaceString + segments[i]

    #if temp_string is not >= avgLength, add it to newtext and reset temp_string
    if len(temp_string) >= avgLength:
      newtext.append(temp_string)
      temp_string = ''
  else:
    #when if len(segments[i]) >= avgLength:
    #if the segment is in the temp_string, append temp_string and reset it
    if segments[i] in temp_string:
      newtext.append(temp_string)
      temp_string = ''
    else:
      #if segment is not in the temp_string, add space and segment
      temp_string += spaceString + segments[i]
      #add to newtext and reset
      newtext.append(temp_string)
      temp_string = ''
```

Comment: This should be close to the idea of what I want. I've edited the question as you suggested. Probably it'll help to clarify my intended results.